# Open .exe item in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, resources

I've added an .exe to my project, as you see in this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1B60.png

Now I want it to open when the user clicks on a button.
I've searched for how to do it but I can only find the Shell function, which requires a path, but I want the .exe to be hidden in the main form. So how can I call it?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("GetHTMLSource.exe");
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: What was the error? Is the executable always in the same directory as your main form is executing?

Comment: I guess that u didn't understand what i want . i want to make this application that hold many other exe . So i want to put them as resorces . what i need is how to open them when i want

Comment: Not sure how you would do that. I don't think you can launch a resource like that...why don't you just include the files in a directory?

Comment: i guess i will do that instead of this, but if i found how to do it i will put it back in the resource again :D